# New SHA256 signature for Redsys in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sha

I have a Ruby on Rails application with Redsys payment platform. They will migrate from old SHA1 to SHA256 in order to keep platform secure.

They give you some examples written in JAVA and PHP but when I write the code in Ruby on Rails, it doesn't work.

**Merchant parameters**

```
def get_merchant_parameters
  amount = @order.total * 100
  hash_params = {
    "Ds_Merchant_Amount"=>amount,
    "Ds_Merchant_Currency"=>"978",
    "Ds_Merchant_Order"=>@order.code,
    "Ds_Merchant_ProductDescription"=>" (cod. #{@order.code})",
    "Ds_Merchant_Titular"=>@order.bill_to_vat_code,
    "Ds_Merchant_MerchantCode"=>tpv_commerce_key,
    "Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL"=>payment_verification_url,
    "Ds_Merchant_UrlOK"=>payment_ok_url,
    "Ds_Merchant_UrlKO"=>payment_ko_url,
    "Ds_Merchant_MerchantName"=>"xxxx",
    "Ds_Merchant_ConsumerLanguage"=>"001",
    "Ds_Merchant_Terminal"=>"001",
    "Ds_Merchant_TransactionType"=>"0"
  }
  Base64.encode64(hash_params.to_json)
end
```

**Signature**

```
def set_electronic_firm
  # 3DES
  des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('DES3')
  des.key = Base64.decode64(tpv_key)

  # ENCRYPTION
  des.encrypt
  key = des.update(@order.code) + des.final

  # SHA256
  Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, @merchant_parameters)).strip()
end
```

**Post form values**

```
@signature_version = "HMAC_SHA256_V1"
@merchant_parameters = get_merchant_parameters
@signature = set_electronic_firm
```

Can anybody notice where am I wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Openssl does not support Zeros Padding out of the box but you can do this yourself by telling Openssl not to pad the data and ensuring the data is a multiple of the block size by adding ‘/0’ characters at the end of the data.

**Solution**

```
def set_electronic_firm
    # 3DES
    des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('des3')
    des.key = Base64.decode64(tpv_key)
    block_length = 8
    des.padding = 0

    # ENCRYPTION
    des.encrypt
    order = @order.code
    order += "\0" until order.bytesize % block_length == 0
    key = des.update(order) + des.final

    # SHA256
    return Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, @merchant_parameters)).gsub("\n",'').strip()
end
```

Comment: A full implementation redsys platform in ruby: https://engineering.sequra.es/2015/10/redsys-hmac-sha256-migration-using-ruby/